# Calling visit() in acceptance test Ember 2.8.0 times out

Tags: ember.js, qunit, acceptance-testing, ember-qunit

I have a simple acceptance script below which only checks for the currentURL. However whenever I run the test it only gives me timeout.

```
import { test } from 'qunit';
import moduleForAcceptance from 'rates-ui/tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance';

moduleForAcceptance('Acceptance | filter panel');

test('visiting /', function(assert) {
  visit('/');
  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/');
  });
  // assert.ok('ok', 'ok');
});
```

Comment: I guess we need more information; such as what are you doing within `model` hook of `index` route? if you do not do anything it simply should work. check out the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/9ded17afcbe96f072b678ece254572a9?openFiles=tests.acceptance.my-acceptance-test.js%2C).

Comment: Update: I found out that the initializer is the culprit for the timeout. however I need some data which is defined inside the initializer. @alptugd

Comment: so did you solve your problem? did you achieve waiting for the initializer?

Answer (score 0):

So the reason behind the time out is that there is an initializer which is required for one of my add-ons.

so for testing, I checked if the app is running on test environment. if it doesn't then  I execute the initializer.